# Bottom Navigation - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy empezando con android studio y estoy creando un bottom navigation, y he creado ya los fragments y lo he añadido, tengo 5 items del menu, pero en dos de ellos me sale una flecha arriba en la parte izquierda como para volver atras, me gustaria saber como se quita y por qué sale solo en esos dos... Adjunto foto. Gracias de antemano.
[image: La flecha de arriba es la que quiero quitar]

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

ya que por lo que veo en tu imagen es el menú principal de tu aplicación lo que yo te recomendaría es quitar totalmente la barra llamada **ActionBar** y esto lo podemos hacer desde la carpeta `app/res/values/themes` y aqui nos encontramos con dos .xml que uno es el *tema claro* y el otro el *tema oscuro* de tu aplicación y entraras a cada uno para modificar el tema en el apartado:

```
<style name="Theme.NombreAplicacion" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Haciendo cambios en el **parent** por el tema que desees, en este caso **NoActionBar** para quitar la barra de tus fragmentos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente,

1 - Añade esta dependencia a tu gradle module:

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5
```

2 - Convierte tu fragment en un navhostfragment añadiento este name en su XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"/>
```

3 - crea una variable en el onCreate donde guardas la referencia de tu fragmente y despues vincula este con la actionbar de este modo:

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myFragment)

NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
```

4 - Después sobreescribe el método onSupportNavigateUp

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
return navController.navigateUp()
    }
```

Y ahora debería aparecer la flecha para volver atrás en todas las pantallas menos en tu navhostfragment. Espero que te ayude, si es así puedes marca la respuesta positivamente para darla por contestada :D